# Neural network for text documents invariant to sentence order

Tags: neural-network, autoencoder

Is there a neural network architecture that I can use to find a low dimensional mapping for documents comprised of multiple sentences such that the mapping is invariant to sentence order?

So, if Doc 1 is:

```
I like dogs. Cats are very nice.
```

and Doc 2 is:

```
Cats are very nice. I like dogs.
```

That in the new space, they would be represented by the same point?